# how to overload and print map<map<list<int>*, vector<int>, myFunctorClass>*, int, myFunctorClass> M1

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates, operator-overloading, functor

Im trying to print map<map<list*, vector, myFunctorClass>*, int, myFunctorClass> M1 as following:

```
    map<map<list<int>*, vector<int>, myFunctorClass>*, int, myFunctorClass> M1{
     {
        new map<list<int>*, vector<int>, myFunctorClass>{
            {new list<int>({91, 92, 93, 94}), vector<int>({5, 6, 7, 8})},
            {new list<int>({11, 12, 13, 14}), vector<int>({5, 6, 7, 8})},
            {new list<int>({12, 22, 32, 42}), vector<int>({5, 6, 7, 8})}
        }, 1
    },
    {
        new map<list<int>*, vector<int>, myFunctorClass>{
            {new list<int>({11, 21, 31, 41}), vector<int>({51, 61, 71, 81})}
        }, 100
    },
    {
        new map<list<int>*, vector<int>, myFunctorClass>{
            {new list<int>({12, 22, 32, 42}), vector<int>({52, 62, 72, 82})}
        }, 16
    }
};
cout << M1 << endl;
```

I used template to overload the operator <<

```
template<class T> ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const map<T*, int, myFunctorClass>& M);
template<class T>ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const list<T*>& L);
template<class T>ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const vector<T>& v);
template <class T1, class T2> ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const map<T1*, T2, myFunctorClass>& m);

template<class T>ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const list<T*>& L) {
str << " < ";
for (auto& i : L) {
    str << *i << " ";
}
str << " > ";
return str;
}
template<class T>ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const vector<T>& v) {
str << " [ ";
for (auto& i : v) {
    str << i << " ";
}
str << " ] ";
return str;
}
template <class T1, class T2> ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const map<T1*, T2, myFunctorClass>& m) {
str << "{ ";
for (auto i : m) {
    str << *i.first << " " << i.second;
}
str << "}";
return str;
}
template<class T>ostream& operator<<(ostream& str, const map<T*, int, myFunctorClass>& M) {
str << "{\n";
for (auto& i : M) {

    str << " { " << i.first;
    str << " " << i.second;
    str << " }\n";
}

str << " \n}";
return str;
}
```

However, I can only have the result like this

```
{
   { 000001EE7768F950 1 }

}
```

it should print something like this(the number are not match):

```
{
{ < 1 2 3 > [ 5 6 7 8 ] < 4 5 3 > [ 15 6 7 8 ] < 11 2 3 > [ 5 26 7 8 ]  2 }
{ < 1 2 3 > [ 5 116 7 8 ] < 4 5 3 > [ 15 6 7 8 ] < 11 2 3 > [ 5 26 7 8 ]  100 }
{ < 1 2 13 > [ 5 26 17 8 ] < 31 2 3 > [ 5 6 77 8 ] < 45 15 3 > [ 11 6 17 8 ]  50 }
}
```

what did I do wrong that it only print the address and only one of the element in the entire map?

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: why are there so many pointers in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The last `operator<<` function is called and it executes the loop over `M` exactly once because there is one element in the top level map. It prints the pointer to `T` and the integer `1` as expected. I presume you wanted it to output the value for `T` instead of the pointer. You need to replace `i.first` with `*i.first`.

This should produce something like:

```
{
    { { 0x60000362d1e0  [ 5 6 7 8  ] } 1 }
}
```

Again, you probably want to output the value instead of the pointer for the inner structure.